# How to put a Button on top of a WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm a C# beginner and I develop a Windows 8 app using C# / XAML. 
I want to put a Close `Button` in the top right corner of a `WebView` but I can't get it done.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Could you post what have you attempted?  And some of your code?

Answer (score 4):

If you target Windows 8 you can't put anything on top of the `WebView` as its rendering is native and independent from the rest of the layout:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN2

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) this should be fixed in Windows 8.1:

> Windows 8.1 introduces changes to the WebView control that fix several
> issues and add new functionality, including:
>
> •Support for displaying
> XAML content (for example, an AppBar) on top of a WebView control.
> This fixes the "airspace problem" in Windows 8 that required you to
> render WebView content using a WebViewBrush if you wanted to overlay
> XAML content.
>
> •Support for using RenderTransform to translate, scale,
> skew, and rotate a WebView control.
>
> •Support for using the Opacity
> property with the WebView control.